# PostgreSQL get results grouped by Name but ordered by modified_date desc for the first element of each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions, sql-in

Suppose that my query:

```
select modified_date, name from table1 where name in (select name from table2 group by name) as a order by name
```

return this results:

[image]

I need to change my query to get results `grouped by Name` but `ordered by modified_date desc` **for the first element of each group**.

Mean the result should be:

[image]

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
data should be *text* in your question, *not* an image of data.

Comment: this will show dates ordered by modified date desc but not grouped by name mean
will show:
05-06-2022 name2
01-05-2022 name1
05-04-2022 name1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your subquery does not need a `GROUP BY` clause because you are not doing any aggregation.
It could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table2
```

but it works fine with a simple:

```
SELECT name FROM table2
```

For your sorting problem, if `modified_date`'s data type is `DATE` you can use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT modified_date, name 
FROM table1 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table2) 
ORDER BY MAX(modified_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name) DESC,
         name, -- just in case 2 names have the same max modified_date
         modified_date DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8a784bbb3e06f28566f8a6edd20bc723).

Comment: Why should MAX and OVER etc. be used instead of just ordering by name desc, modified_date desc?

Comment: @JonasMetzler the subquery is not used in the ORDER BY clause. It just filters the results.